# stringstream operator<< crash (malloc_consolidate )

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000003663c70485 in malloc_consolidate () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003663c70485 in malloc_consolidate () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003663c72a6c in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003663c74cde in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000003d364af4aa in operator new(unsigned long) ()
   **/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x0000003d364900ee in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) ()
   from **/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

The code is :

```
...
       if (logger->isEnabledFor(Level::ALL)) {\
            std::ostringstream oss; \
            oss << message; \
            logger->forcedLog(Level::ALL, oss.str(), __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        } \
...
```

It said that, ostringstream's operator<< isn't a re-enterable function. is that right?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to go back and mark some of your other questions as answered, if an answer is suitable to you. Also, none of the standard library is necessarily thread-safe in any respect, the current standard is completely silent on it. (Indeed, I don't know of any that are.) You always need to make sure access to shared data is protected by a lock (or atomic, which I'll say is technically a hardware lock). We can't solve your problem though, since you haven't really showed us what causes it, just a couple lines of code that initiate it. What's `message`, what's the context, what's your code?

Comment: Could be that `operator<<(ostream &, whatever type message is)` is not re-entrant.  Depends on the type of `message` and your implementation of its insertion operator (if it is a custom type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be because stringstream::operator<< is non-reentrant function.